# installed laravel but unable to view the project

Tags: php, laravel

I have just installed and downloaded laravel and installed via composer the laravel folder is located in my htdocs/laravel now when I type in localhost/laravell it is showing me list of files how can i access the project I am new to laravel lsearched alot but non of them help me out can anyone help me out with my query please

Comment: try `php artisan serve`

Comment: Mcrypt ph extention required getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup your virtual hosts properly:

**1.** Go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and open "hosts", add (you may change the domain to your liking):

```
127.0.0.1   dev.site
```

**2.** Go to your virtual hosts file (on xampp it would be YOUR_XAMPP_DIRECTORY\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf), and add:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "YOUR_LARAVEL_DIRECTORY\public"
    ServerAdmin dev.site
    <Directory "YOUR_LARAVEL_DIRECTORY">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: not working still I am seeing files your first step i did not do because my xamp is isntalled in E drive does it will effect still i follow this step also  at this place YOUR_LARAVEL_DIRECTORY I replaced with laravel is that okay ?

Comment: @MarkAlan You still need to do the first step. YOUR_LARAVEL_DIRECTORY needs to be replaced with the path of your laravel project directory.

Comment: sorry for asking and confirming again my project is in e:xamp\htdocs\laravel so your path directy will be only project name right like laravel?

Comment: after your solution and follwing steps getting this eror now (You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.)

Comment: Hi, no... The path needs to be the directory of the laravel project, not relative directory but the actual directory of it.

Comment: MY DIRECTORY NAME IS LARAVEL BET i am getting above error :(